# Workflow InstancePersistenceCommand was interrupted error when copy Database from one server machine to another machine old Databse working fine

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, workflow

I have two servers both have same SQL Server 2008 installed. When I restore the same database on another machine, this error occurs:

> The execution of an InstancePersistenceCommand was interrupted because the instance key '761c9e4a-2835-d6ec-6017-581a5fbfb698' was not associated to an instance. This can occur because the instance or key has been cleaned up, or because the key is invalid. The key may be invalid if the message it was generated from was sent at the wrong time or contained incorrect correlation data.

Comment: This isn't a SQL Server message. SQL Server doesn't have a workflow. Where did this message come from? It *can't* have come from the `RESTORE` command. What else did you restore? Did you try restoring AppFabric perhaps? Or an application that uses Workflow Foundation?

Comment: yes You are right is not SQL server error it come in c# when calling Workflowservice.xamlx also please check image on link https://s23.postimg.org/x1zyxfgcb/img.png

Comment: Then I *strongly* suggest you rewrite the question to ask what you really want to ask, and use the proper tags. You missed a database or file somewhere, whatever it is that you use for workflow persistence